# How to customize Swing components (to standardize fonts)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to make Java Swing components with standard font size, so I customized the components to "HAHA components" by making subclasses extended from the swing component class.

However, the customized `JTextfield` cannot be typed and `setText`. The customized Button shows no text. (I sure I did not write other codes that could change the properties of the customized components).

After debugging, I found that if I delete the `setFont` statement in `HAHATextField`, that text field object can be typed and `setText`. And further if I `setFont` through the `HAHATextField` instance, it works properly.

Why did this not work properly? And what is the proper way to do?

The codes are below.

```
class HAHAButton extends JButton
{
    HAHAButton(String haha)
    {
        super(haha);
        this.setFont(new Font("haha",Font.BOLD,fontsize));
    }
}

class HAHALabel extends JLabel
{
    HAHALabel(String haha)
    {
        super(haha);
        this.setFont(new Font("haha",Font.BOLD,fontsize));
    }
}

class HAHATextField extends JTextField
{
    HAHATextField(int haha)
    {
        super(haha);
        this.setFont(new Font("haha",Font.BOLD,fontsize));
        this.setText("haha");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"swing components with standard font size"* Probably better off handling this via a custom look & feel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thx for the polishing, I don't know how to paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the "haha" font is. Whenever you test something new, test the logic with system classes and objects.

Also we have no idea what the fontsize is or if it even has a value.

So you would do something like:

```
//this.setFont(new Font("haha", Font.BOLD, fontsize));
setFont( getFont().deriveFont( 24.0f ) );
```

If this works then you can try a different font family:

```
setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));
```

If this works then you try your custom font.

This will help isolate where the problem occurs.

> And what is the proper way to do?

If you want to change this for ALL the components then sometimes you can take advantage of the UIManager. At the start of your class BEFORE you create an components you can do:

```
UIManager.put("TextField.font", new FontUIResource( yourFontHere ));
```

Now this will be the default font used when the component is created.

Again, start with a standard system Font for a simple test. And then try the "haha" Font.

You would need to do this for the other components as well.

Check out [UIManager Default](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more information. Don't go crazy trying to change these defaults as it is not guaranteed that each LAF will use these properties.

Comment: thx. Seems I solved this problem. I forgot to say that the classes are inner classes and fontsize is an initialized const int. But now I discover a new problem that it seems i cannot setFont by the statement "HAHATextFieldobject.setFont( getFont().deriveFont( 24.0f ) );" before creating a frame. The program throws NullPointerException. But  "HAHATextFieldobject.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));" works. Why?

Comment: I have no ideas what the structure of your code is like. There is no reason to create  JFrame before setting the Font of a Swing component. However all GUI components should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Post  a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem when you ask a question so we can see what you are doing.